# com.ebay.app.pres.service.hosting.WebServiceDisabledException: The web service eBayAPI is not properly configured or not found and is disabled

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, ebay-api

I am using eBay API to call GetSessionId method in my ASP.NET MVC4 application.
But I am getting this error

**com.ebay.app.pres.service.hosting.WebServiceDisabledException: The web service eBayAPI is not properly configured or not found and is disabled.**

My code is here...

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult f()
    {
        string endpointURL5 = _apiUrl + "?callname = GetSessionID" +
                         "&siteid = " + "0" +
                         "&appid = " + _appId +
                         "&version = " + "768" +
                         "&routing = default";
        eBayAPIInterfaceClient service = new eBayAPIInterfaceClient();

        System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress address1 = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(endpointURL5);
        service.Endpoint.Address = address1;
        string version1 = "768";
        GetSessionIDRequestType gs = new GetSessionIDRequestType();
        gs.RuName = _ruName;
        gs.Version = version1;


        CustomSecurityHeaderType cred = new CustomSecurityHeaderType();
        UserIdPasswordType cr = new UserIdPasswordType();
        //cr.Username = "esandbox10539";
        //cr.Password = "nomistakes";
        cr.AppId = _appId;
        cr.AuthCert = _authCert;
        cr.DevId = _devId;
        cred.Credentials = cr;

        GetSessionIDResponseType sessionID = service.GetSessionID(ref cred, gs);
        Session["sessionID"] = (sessionID.Any.GetValue(0) as XmlElement).InnerXml;

        r.Data = _signInUrl + "?SignIn&runame=" + gs.RuName + "&SessID=" + Server.UrlEncode(Session["sessionID"].ToString());
        return Json(r, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

This was working fine 7 month ago.But now I am getting this error 
I have checked credentials but credentials are perfect. My _apiUrl is 'https://api.ebay.com/wsapi'

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Check if your eBay API access Token is expired or not.

Comment: Thank you for your approach.But the above code is for getting new eBay API access Token.I am tring to get sessionID and make a url to redirect for user permission to get token.If user permit it redirect to my site url and I am getting new token using fetchtoken

Comment: now this is not working and I m getting error on "GetSessionIDResponseType sessionID = service.GetSessionID(ref cred, gs);" even I have created a new user account and a developer account for fresh new credentials. But still getting the same error

Comment: As far as I know eBay API won't return SessionID is the Auth Token is expired. I am using eBay's PHP api and I haven't used SessionID to do any operations i.e. getting item details updating item descriptions, etc.

Comment: I am trying to generate token via eBay API .I followed this link. I am stuck at 2nd point under the header 'Summary of the Process' http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/guides/ebayfeatures/Basics/Tokens-MultipleUsers.html. My previous user token is active because I am fetching orders,updating shipments etc successfully and I haven't used sessionID there. I need multiple token for different user account.

Comment: The thing is if your token is expired then eBay API dosen't returns sessionID and to renew the token we need sessionID, best thing to do is before doing any api call check is the token is still valid and when does it expires if the expire date is near i.e. within month then renew it because you will have valid token which will give you sessionID to renew then near to expire token. I faced same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is PHP code to check whether your auth token is valid or not. Sorry I am a PHP developer so don't know much about ASP

```
$feed = <<< EOD
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GetTokenStatusRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
<RequesterCredentials>
<eBayAuthToken>$this->auth_token</eBayAuthToken>
</RequesterCredentials>
<ErrorLanguage>en_GB</ErrorLanguage>
<MessageID>$messageID</MessageID>
<Version>$this->api_version</Version>
<WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>
</GetTokenStatusRequest>​
EOD;

$feed = trim($feed);
        $site_id = 3;//3 For UK
        $headers = array
            (
            'X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL: ' . $this->api_version,
            'X-EBAY-API-DEV-NAME: ' . $this->dev_id,
            'X-EBAY-API-APP-NAME: ' . $this->app_id,
            'X-EBAY-API-CERT-NAME: ' . $this->cert_id,
            'X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME: ' . $call_name,
            'X-EBAY-API-SITEID: ' . $site_id,
        );

        // Send request to eBay and load response in $response
        $connection = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.ebay.com/ws/api.dll');
        curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $feed);
        curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $response = curl_exec($connection);
        curl_close($connection);
```